# Ansible group_vars visible to non-members of group

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am using Ansible `2.0.0.2`.

I have inventory file like this:

```
[webproxy]
testserver

[database]
testserver

[application]
testserver

[testing:children]
webproxy
database
```

I run roles from playbooks like this:

```
---
- hosts: application

  become: true

  roles:
    - application
```

I define variables for testing environment in `group_vars/testing`.
I have roles `webproxy`, `database` and `application`.

Since `application` group is not included in the `testing` group I would expect running the `application` role to fail because I have defined required variables only for testing group. In reality running `application.yaml` works it is able to use variables defined in `group_vars/testing`. Is that correct behaviour?

The `testing` group seems have at least some effect, because if I remove it completely from inventory file, then running application roles fails because of undefined variables as expected.

Are `group_vars` supposed to work like this?
Is this maybe caused by the fact that I install roles on the same host?
(I don't have access to multiple machines right now so I cannot test with each role having their own machine.)

I have been reading through Ansible documentation such as [Group vars doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#group-variables) but have not found answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are `group_vars` supposed to work like this?

Yes.

> Is this maybe caused by the fact that I install roles on the same host?

Yes. Facts are bound to hosts, not groups.

This also means that the same variable values defined in multiple group_vars will get overwritten.